# AWS: RDS Instance change DB Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I had only one Schema called "`Test`".  It shows up in Dashboard next to **DB Name** (in yellow in the image below):

[image]

I added another Schema to my instance via MySQLWorkbench, lets say its called "`NewDB`".

How do I change the **DB Name** to my new Schema, "`NewDB`", in my Dashboard?

Comment: Did you find a way of doing this? How can such a simple thing be so hard? Is AWS really this atrocious?

Comment: You can't change in the console.  I had to login via MySQLWorkbench and change the name there.

Comment: @Mark Aroni  Just deleted and recreated instance. Its a cruel and sadist world.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify it once you launch RDS instance.
If you really want to change it, then take a snapshot of your instance & create new instance with that snapshot for your required DB name.

Comment: That does not work using posgresql, at least with restore to Point in time `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime operation: DBName must be null when Restoring for this Engine.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to change `DBName` parameter for SQL database in RDS. The only way to do it (why?) is to create a new instance with a `null` or new DB name in it's place.